# Выделение текста в textview

Tags: android, android-textview

Я знаю, что начиная с версии API 11 можно выделять текст из textview, но можно ли как-то выделить одно конкретное слово, на которое тапнул юзер? Ну или хотя бы можно ли как-то определить место на экране, в которое было произведено нажатие?

Comment: Используйте метод setSelection(int start, int stop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Координаты нажатия приходят в OnTouchListener, его с помощью setOnTouchListener() можно повесить как на все activity, так и на конкретную вьюху.

Позицию в тексте по координатам внутри вьюхи можно получить так:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5817004/1263771